# Windows controls layout not changed after configuring through Elementary Tweaks

Tags: window-management

I did a fresh install of 5.1 and installed elementary tweaks to get my go-to windows controls layout. All the system apps and apps like Chrome and Firefox have the changed controls, but apps installed from flatpak like Spotify and other gtk? apps have the default eOS format.
How can I change these to the windows controls layout?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your screenshots you want the buttons to be on the right side with winboze order. In order to achieve this, execute this into the terminal application:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

If you want the buttons to be on the left site use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you're the best human being ever !!

Comment: No worries, this is the reason of StackExchange, to help each other. Can you accept the answer? use the grey thickbox in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer a graphical tool, "gnome-tweak-tool" ("ajustements" in French) works well to act on windows (enable "minimize windows"; choose left or right for the "close" or "minimize" buttons (in French, sorry) :

[image]